# "scanf" as a condition in while loops

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, do-while

I need to determine the size of an input (potentially infinite) using the "scanf" function. 
Now I have limitations so I cant use strings, arrays, or basically anything that is not the function.

```
char input;
int counter = 0;
while (scanf(" %c",&input) == 1) counter++;
```

The problem i'm facing is that the loop is infinite,
I figured that my end condition is probably wrong. I've tried all of this.

```
while (scanf(" %c",&input) > 0)
while (scanf(" %c",&input) != -1)
while (scanf(" %c",&input) != EOF)
```

I've also tried "do-while".

Thanks for the helpers.

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of inout specifiers matched, so I would use the condition `== 1`.  Also, in this case I would *not* use the leading space before `%c`.  (I'm not sure either of these changes explain your problem, though.)

Comment: How do you know the loop is infinite? Did you let it run forever?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `scanf`, and not `getchar`?

Comment: @SteveSummit "Now I have limitations so I cant use strings, arrays, or basically anything that is not the function" makes me think of a school assignment

Comment: @user3121023 I need to create an in-code option for the assignment.

Comment: It's impossible to determine an infinite size in finite time :)

Comment: @SteveSummit Doesn't work. Can't use anything other than scanf.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well i'm assuming :) the code won't continue as if the program is waiting on another input. Only thing that works is Ctrl+D or exiting the program.

Comment: How are you feeding the input? How are you signaling the end of input?

Comment: @bolov feeding it via user input. I can't signal the end of the input because the instructor said he will just enter random phrases so I can't really set an end by myself.

Comment: I tried your program and it worked fine.  I got wrong answers until I got rid of the leading space before `%c`.  I ran the program with input redirected from a file, using `<`.  I also ran the program with input from the keyboard, terminating my input with control-D.  Again, this all worked fine.  But if you're reading from the keyboard, and the user doesn't type control-D (or control-Z on DOS/Windows), then yes, the program is going to wait forever for input.

Comment: @SteveSummit So the only way to signal the end of the stream (when dealing with keyboard input) is via CTRL+D?

Comment: @Nix Under Unix and Unix-like systems, yes, that's the basic (and pretty much the only) way.  If you really really wanted to you could write code to have it time out and exit after (say) a minute of inactivity, but that's surprisingly difficult to do, and almost certainly not what your instructor is expecting.

Comment: of course it works: https://ideone.com/Pq8QHH

Comment: @Nix So, just to be clear: your program works fine as long as you terminate the input with control-D, but you're worried about some situation where the user doesn't (or can't, or won't) type control-D?

Comment: @SteveSummit Exactly. The code needs approval of the instructor. I'm will ask him if it is acceptable this way or if I should find another.

Comment: @Nix and how do you expect your program to end if you don't signal the end of the input? Yes, on linux pressing `CTRL-D` send the end of input signal to the program. So yes, that is what you have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Assuming that input will be space seperated and will terminate when user presses "Enter".
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char input;
        while(1)
        {
                if(scanf("%c", &input))
               {
                        /*
                        * do someething
                         */
                        if(input=='\n')
                    {
                            break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            printf("%c\n", input);
                    }
            }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This helped alot! a little correction though - In my case there is a need to iterate through every char while discarding the former empty spaces. So you'll need to add `scanf(" %c",&input)` outside of the loop for the first iteration.